# Not sure how to do this specific insert into sql table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this script:

```
 SELECT 'pro' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen where TradesManAccountType_Value = 2 AND HasTradeListing = 1
 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'std' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen tm
 INNER JOIN Membership.Members m ON m.MemberId = tm.MemberId
 INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership am ON am.UserId = m.AspNetUserId
 WHERE tm.TradesManAccountType_Value = 1 AND tm.HasTradeListing = 1 AND am.IsApproved = 1

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'listed' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen where HasTradeListing = 1

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 'all' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen
 insert into Admin.VersionHistory values(4,cnt,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) //is NOT correct
```

this produces:

```
 1     pro          32549
 2     std          13096
 3     listed   230547
 4     all          231638
```

I want to add the above as rows in my table: Admin.VersionHistory which has columns VersionHistory type int auto-increment and is the ID, Version which is of type varchar(50) and a datatime stamp

thanks

Comment: Your question has become a bit of a mess now.  First off, you can't use 'all' as your table's ID column.  Use a proper ID for that. Looks like a column `Description` is missing from your Admin.VersionHistory table.  And what you are trying to insert to `Version` (a count from  another table) doesn't make any sense.  Maybe you should simplify your question and explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: And most importantly: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(updated with new info from OP)
From the top of my head, it would look something like this.

```
INSERT INTO Admin.VersionHistory (Version, NumberOf, DateAndTime)
SELECT descript, CAST(cnt AS VARCHAR), SYSDATE
FROM
(
SELECT 'pro' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen where TradesManAccountType_Value = 2 AND HasTradeListing = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'std' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen tm
INNER JOIN Membership.Members m ON m.MemberId = tm.MemberId
INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership am ON am.UserId = m.AspNetUserId
WHERE tm.TradesManAccountType_Value = 1 AND tm.HasTradeListing = 1 AND am.IsApproved = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'listed' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen where HasTradeListing = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'all' as descript, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Trade.TradesMen
) ;
```

This is assuming the `VersionHistoryId`column is automatically seeded by the database.  With each insert, an ID number will be automatically inserted.

Not sure what you want to achieve with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` column though.  I put `SYSDATE` as a timestamp.

The `NumberOf` column contains the count data.  Name it as you see fit.

Comment: thanks but i get an error: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Admin.VersionHistory' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. How do I work around this? was this suppose to be ON when the table was created?

Comment: I can't answer that, as I obviously don't know how the Admin.VersionHistory table looks like.  Do you have a PK on your table (you apparently do) ? What's it called ? Is it an 'autonumber' ? etc...  Please add this information to your original question so we can help you.

Comment: thanks, why am i getting invalid column name on the descript column of SELECT descript, CAST(cnt AS VARCHAR), SYSDATE? what column names must i use there? sorry i am very new to all this and dont understand it all yet :)

Comment: Hm... no idea to be honest.  The resultset of the `UNION`s contains just the _descript_ and _cnt_ columns... Are you sure the error relates to the _descript_ column ?

Btw, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Check the columns on your target table. If you can't find a clue, paste the create script of the `VersionHistory` table in your OP.  We can't help you, if you don't help us ;)

Comment: sorry i misunderstood what I was supposed to do in the first place and would like this post to be deleted because that is not what I was supposed to do :) can some one delete this thread pls?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into Admin.VersionHistory 
SELECT 'all', COUNT(*),current_timestamp FROM Trade.TradesMen
```